# My web api get 500 internal server after deploy to azure api management

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-web-api2, azure-api-management

I am new to azure app service, i have used visual studio to deploy my web api to azure api management. i am doing a mobile application project, I need to make local ssms database data sync to azure cloud. because my web api is connect to ssms database, and it has error when i am testing it in azure api management, it response 500 internal server error, but i have the weatherforecast **GET** Sample, and this api work normal, it response 200 ok. i don't know what i have done wrong to the web api or i set up wrong in the azure.

ScreenShots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the `.NET Framework` you are using ?

Comment: @Harshitha .Net Frame work v4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below steps to deploy sync the local DB to Azure SQL Server.

> I need to make local ssms database data sync to azure cloud.

- In `Azure Portal` => Create a new `SQL Database Server`.

[image]

- Set Admin
  [image]

In `Local DB` => Right click on the `DB` => `Tasks` =>select  `Deploy Database to Microsoft Azure SQL Database`.

[image]

- Click on `Connect` , provide the `Server name` from `Azure Portal` (SQL Server Overview page).

[image]

- Initially I got the below error.
  [image]
- To access/ Connect `Azure SQL DB` , we need to enable `Public network access` and add `Firewall rules` in `Azure SQL Server`.

[image]

- Now I have connected to `Azure SQL server` and deployed local DB `Test` to `Azure SQL Server` without any issues.

[image]

- SQL Database in Azure contains all the data which we have in local DB.
- Now if we want to make any changes to the DB, from SSMS we need to connect to the `Azure SQL DB` and make required changes.

[image]

- I have inserted data by connecting `Azure SQL DB` , you can see the changes in portal.

[image]

- Now we need to provide the `Azure SQL Connection string` in the `Web.config` file of the `ASP.Net Web API`.
- Copy the connection string from `Azure SQL DB` and paste it in the `Web.config` file.

[image]

- Replace the password with your Password.

Comment: i want to ask my ssms database have many datas and the ssms database will keep updating, will it keep update data to azure when i add new data to the ssms database?

Comment: We have [Azure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-sql-server-configure?view=azuresql) option in [Azure SQL DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVtMo.png).

Comment: I can't make the firewall works, i don't know why

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot of that.

Comment: i have added screenshots, but it said i don't have 10 post reputation to post image